# could not convert string to float 9DOF Razor IMU

Tags: python

I am receiving the "could not convert string to float" error in this code. Could anyone take a look to see what is wrong please? I am working with the 9DOF Razor IMU connected to the PC using an FTDI, both from sparkfun. I am trying to see the axis x,y and z and the yaw, pitch and roll bars moving while I rotate my Razor, but I am receiving this error. It's the first project I'm working on, so everything I am doing is based on tutorials and blogs. English is not my motherlanguage, so sorry 'bout any english mistakes i've made. Thank you.

```
# This script needs VPhyton, pyserial and pywin modules


from visual import *
import serial
import string
import math

from time import time

grad2rad = 3.141592/180.0

# Check your COM port and baud rate
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM13',baudrate=57600, timeout=1)

# Main scene
scene=display(title="9DOF Razor IMU test")
scene.range=(1.2,1.2,1.2)
#scene.forward = (0,-1,-0.25)
scene.forward = (1,0,-0.25)
scene.up=(0,0,1)

# Second scene (Roll, Pitch, Yaw)
scene2 = display(title='9DOF Razor IMU test',x=0, y=0, width=500, height=200,center=(0,0,0),         background=(0,0,0))
scene2.range=(1,1,1)
scene.width=500
scene.y=200

scene2.select()
#Roll, Pitch, Yaw
cil_roll = cylinder(pos=(-0.4,0,0),axis=(0.2,0,0),radius=0.01,color=color.red)
cil_roll2 = cylinder(pos=(-0.4,0,0),axis=(-0.2,0,0),radius=0.01,color=color.red)
cil_pitch = cylinder(pos=(0.1,0,0),axis=(0.2,0,0),radius=0.01,color=color.green)
cil_pitch2 = cylinder(pos=(0.1,0,0),axis=(-0.2,0,0),radius=0.01,color=color.green)
#cil_course = cylinder(pos=(0.6,0,0),axis=(0.2,0,0),radius=0.01,color=color.blue)
#cil_course2 = cylinder(pos=(0.6,0,0),axis=(-0.2,0,0),radius=0.01,color=color.blue)
arrow_course = arrow(pos=(0.6,0,0),color=color.cyan,axis=(-0.2,0,0), shaftwidth=0.02, fixedwidth=1)

#Roll,Pitch,Yaw labels
label(pos=(-0.4,0.3,0),text="Roll",box=0,opacity=0)
label(pos=(0.1,0.3,0),text="Pitch",box=0,opacity=0)
label(pos=(0.55,0.3,0),text="Yaw",box=0,opacity=0)
label(pos=(0.6,0.22,0),text="N",box=0,opacity=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.6,-0.22,0),text="S",box=0,opacity=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.38,0,0),text="W",box=0,opacity=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.82,0,0),text="E",box=0,opacity=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.75,0.15,0),height=7,text="NE",box=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.45,0.15,0),height=7,text="NW",box=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.75,-0.15,0),height=7,text="SE",box=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.45,-0.15,0),height=7,text="SW",box=0,color=color.yellow)

L1 = label(pos=(-0.4,0.22,0),text="-",box=0,opacity=0)
L2 = label(pos=(0.1,0.22,0),text="-",box=0,opacity=0)
L3 = label(pos=(0.7,0.3,0),text="-",box=0,opacity=0)

# Main scene objects
scene.select()
# Reference axis (x,y,z)
arrow(color=color.green,axis=(1,0,0), shaftwidth=0.02, fixedwidth=1)
arrow(color=color.green,axis=(0,-1,0), shaftwidth=0.02 , fixedwidth=1)
arrow(color=color.green,axis=(0,0,-1), shaftwidth=0.02, fixedwidth=1)
# labels
label(pos=(0,0,0.8),text="9DOF Razor IMU test",box=0,opacity=0)
label(pos=(1,0,0),text="X",box=0,opacity=0)
label(pos=(0,-1,0),text="Y",box=0,opacity=0)
label(pos=(0,0,-1),text="Z",box=0,opacity=0)
# IMU object
platform = box(length=1, height=0.05, width=1, color=color.red)
p_line = box(length=1,height=0.08,width=0.1,color=color.yellow)
plat_arrow = arrow(color=color.green,axis=(1,0,0), shaftwidth=0.06, fixedwidth=1)


f = open("Serial"+str(time())+".txt", 'w')

roll=0
pitch=0
yaw=0
while 1:
    line = ser.readline()
    line = line.replace("!ANG:","")   # Delete "!ANG:"
    print line
    f.write(line)                     # Write to the output log file
    words = string.split(line,",")    # Fields split
    if len(words) > 2:
       try:
            roll = float(words[0])*grad2rad
            pitch = float(words[1])*grad2rad
            yaw = float(words[2])*grad2rad
        except:
            print "Invalid line"

        axis=(cos(pitch)*cos(yaw),-cos(pitch)*sin(yaw),sin(pitch)) 
        up=(sin(roll)*sin(yaw)+cos(roll)*sin(pitch)*cos(yaw),sin(roll)*cos(yaw)-    cos(roll)*sin(pitch)*sin(yaw),-cos(roll)*cos(pitch))
        platform.axis=axis
        platform.up=up
        platform.length=1.0
        platform.width=0.65
        plat_arrow.axis=axis
        plat_arrow.up=up
        plat_arrow.length=0.8
        p_line.axis=axis
        p_line.up=up
        cil_roll.axis=(0.2*cos(roll),0.2*sin(roll),0)
        cil_roll2.axis=(-0.2*cos(roll),-0.2*sin(roll),0)
        cil_pitch.axis=(0.2*cos(pitch),0.2*sin(pitch),0)
        cil_pitch2.axis=(-0.2*cos(pitch),-0.2*sin(pitch),0)
        arrow_course.axis=(0.2*sin(yaw),0.2*cos(yaw),0)
        L1.text = str(float(words[0]))
        L2.text = str(float(words[1]))
        L3.text = str(float(words[2]))        
ser.close
f.close
```

Comment: On which line is this error thrown?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To help us help you, try trimming this down to a _minimal_ example (2-3 lines, probably) that we can run by itself and demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Well, after Khalid's help, my only problem is that I am reading "Invalid line" - line 96 of the code - and I am not able to see the IMU test working (the board and the bars aren't moving)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using some old tutorials if the are suggesting stuff like `string.split(line,",")`

From your source, it seems the problem is here:

```
L1.text = str(float(words[0]))
L2.text = str(float(words[1]))
L3.text = str(float(words[2]))
```

You are trying to convert something to a float, that Python can't convert to a number. From the looks of it, these are text labels, so why not try:

```
L1.text = words[0]
L2.text = words[1]
L3.text = words[2]
```

Some more tips:

```
words = line.split(',') # instead of: words = string.split(line,",")
ser.close() # close is a function, so you should call it.
f.close()
```

Comment: well, thank you for the help, I'm not seeing the string-float error anymore, but I am still receiving the "invalid line" error, so I still can't see the graphics =/ Do u have another suggestion of changes I should make?

Comment: Without your changes, I was receiving: 

values for YPR (yaw,pitch,roll);
Invalid line;
Traceback (most recent call last):;
File "location", line 114, in (module);
L1.text=str(float(words[0]));
ValueError: could not convert string to float: #YPR = a value;

After the modifications I receive:;

Invalid line;
#YPR = some values;

Invalid line;
#YPR = some values;

Invalid line;
#YPR = some values;

And it keeps going, giving me the correct values, but the IMU tests don't show me anything. The bars don't move and the red board doesn't even appears.

Answer (score 0):

make the following changes to the code:

- replace the line

  ```
  line = line.replace("!ANG:","")
  ```

  with

  ```
  line = line.replace("#YPR=","")
  ```
- replace the split line as told earlier and that should just do the trick!